# Android - Alert Dialog force close

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to display the alert dialog below but it force closes, i m little bit confused about what the context should be.
This dialog is shown when an image is clicked.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
getApplicationContext(), R.style.TitleDialog);
builder.setTitle("Sorry for Inconvinience");
builder.setMessage("You need to install MX Player or VLC Media Player");
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

I am a beginner any help will be appreciated
full onclicklistener

```
ib2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                try {
                    startActivity(i2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Sorry for Inconvinience");
                    builder.setMessage("You need to install MX Player or VLC Media Player, here is the link: ");
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please check your Internet Connection.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat output ?

Comment: Not sure that you can use the application context in your builder, see e.g. [this awesome article on contexts](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Sorry for Inconvinience");
        buildersetMessage("You need to install MX Player or VLC Media Player");
       .show();
```

The above code should work.
I don't know what

```
getApplicationContext(), R.style.TitleDialog);
```

is used for though.

Comment: what is 'a' (in the context place)?

Comment: Sorry I had the dialog in a method. I've fixed the code. So it should be your activity name.this .

Comment: i copied your code exactly same, but it force closes. help plz

Comment: I'll need to see more code man. because it works for me. Have you got it in a setOnClickListener on your image?

Comment: thanks for your help, i showed toast and dialog at the same time and hence it force closed

Comment: Try to change  `ib2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()`  to : `ib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`

Comment: @SaeedJassani Glad you figured it out. :-D